# Biggest noncommutative group $N$ where a group $G$ is normal.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Given a finite group $G$, it is possible to obtain the biggest non commutative group $N$ such that $G\lhd N$ with $N\neq G$, $\vert N\vert < \infty$ and $N$ not a direct or semidirect product?

Comment: Given a finite group $G$, can you find at least one noncommutative, finite, non-direct/semidirect product group $N$ containing $G$ as a proper normal subgroup? If the answer is no, then you would first need to find conditions for which such groups would exist. If the answer is yes, then the means of obtaining that answer might shed light on how to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Given $G$ and any non-commutative finite group $H$, then $G\times H$ and $G\times H\times H$ and $G\times H\times H\times H$ etc. are all non-isomorphic groups whose orders tend to infinity that have the desired properties.

To address the edits:

In what sense do you mean "not a direct or semidirect product"?  If you had an example $N$, what exactly in your imagined condition stops me from just taking the direct product of $N$ with literally any other finite group?  Or from taking the [holomorph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorph_(mathematics)) of $N$?  Do you want $N$ to be indecomposable?  Do you want $N$ to not admit any non-trivial semi-direct product whatsoever, for any subgroups?  Or only no semi-direct product expression involving $G$ as one of the subgroups?

The concept of "maximal such group" is unlikely to be well-defined, especially not within finite groups.  I'm having trouble imagining a definition that would even guarantee a unique isomorphism class at that order.  "Minimal" is more likely to have a meaningful answer, though you still have to be careful to specify what you mean--for much the same reasons, but "maximal" requires rather strong conditions to stop you from just constructing arbitrary towers of examples, whereas "minimal" tends to be much more intrinsically restrictive.

Comment: And if it isn't a direct product?

Comment: For the record, the "no direct/semidirect" condition wasn't added until after I posted my answer.

Comment: Yes, I know, sorry for that, was a mistake of my question. Anyway I voted positive yout answer because you were right.

Comment: @MonsieurGalois I've added some comments on the matter.

Comment: In my extra comment I'm trying to avoid the idea of coordinates, because I'm considering the idea of a group that is of the style like $S_n$. The idea borns from the idea of building a group bigger than the normalizer of <(1,2,3,4,5)> in $S_5$ only adding elements to the group.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is a resounding no.  There are all manner of ways of "putting groups together" so-as to satisfy your normality requirement that have no restrictions on what those initial groups look like (esp. one of them could be monstrously large [pun intended]).

What you're interested in is fusion systems.  It's technical but has elementary prerequisites.  I suggest the following:

http://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/C.W.Parker/Fusion/fusion-intro.pdf

It is a way of "zippering" groups together along subsets that is actually quite beautiful and has some geometric applications, but I'm not the best person to give you many details, sadly!

Comment: Yes John, I'm working on fusion systems, but my curiosity is on looking for the exotic ones, and knowing this question would be useful for that.